# Set background color for all UITableViewCells in iOS app

Tags: ios, uitableview, background-color

What's the easiest way to set the `backgroundColor` of all `UITableViewCell`s in an iOS app?

Consider an app that has a relatively large number of `UITableViewController` subclasses. The background color is specified via a web service. So using the color in each tableViewController is probably not the easiest thing to do.

Perhaps every tableViewCell could inherit a `UITableViewCell` subclass where the color is set for all derived classes? There might be an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be a singleton. for example:

```
@interface ColorThemeSingleton : NSObject
@property (strong, atomic) UIColor *tableViewBackgroundColor;
+(ColorThemeSingleton *)sharedInstance;
@end
```

and the `.m`:

```
#import "ColorThemeSingleton.h"
@implementation ColorThemeSingleton
@synthesize tableViewBackgroundColor = _tableViewBackgroundColor;
+(ColorThemeSingleton *)sharedInstance{
    static ColorThemeSingleton *shared = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        shared = [[ColorThemeSingleton alloc] init];
    });
    return shared;
}
-(id)init{
    if ((self = [super init])){
        _tableViewBackgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; // Default color
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Then just after the `if(cell==nil){}` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you would add:

```
cell.backgroundColor = [ColorThemeSingleton sharedInstance].tableViewBackgroundColor;
```

And when you load you color from the web, set the value of the property to the fetched color. The next time a cell runs through `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` the color will be the new color.

So basically just add the `#import""` and `cell.backgroundColor =` to the `tableView`'s `dataSource`. To me that's a lot better than changing the `UITableViewCell`'s class on every controller.